# WinXPe NDIS 5.1 Device Driver IPv6

Tags: device-driver, wdk, ndis

Writing WinXPe NDIS 5.1 device driver. Started with Intel E100 driver source from DDK and adapting to Altera triple-speed ethernet core. Receive packet through scatter gather DMA working well, can see good data. Transmit packet through separate scatter gather DMA claims to be working well. Problem is that ipconfig shows IPv6 only IP address for the NIC. Control Panel, Network Configuration, Internet Protocol, has set static IPv4 IP address and no DHCP. But ipconfig doesn't see it. Can't find any OIDs which appear to tell WinXPe anything about IPv6 versus IPv4. Control Panel, Network Configuration correctly updates itself for ethernet connect and disconnect, but nothing seems to please ipconfig. Where is ipconfig getting its IPv6 information, and how can the driver affect it? Thanks.

Comment: More info: Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration shows IPEnabled set to 0 for my NDIS device, but set to -1 for NDIS devices that ipconfig shows an IPV4 IP address. What is setting or affecting IPEnabled? Win7 "netsh interface ipv4" appears to be able to affect the configuration, but WinXPe netsh is much more limited.

Comment: More info: implemented Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration EnableStatic, but it fails with result=84, "IP not enabled". Have hand edited registry CurrentControlSet, Control, Services, Tcpip, Parameters, Interfaces, <GUID>, to set IPEnabled to 1 but that doesn't help. My <GUID> has less than half the elements that functional <GUID> have. What is responsible for populating these elements?

Comment: Those questions are usually better placed on the NTDEV mailing list over at OSR Online :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was an incomplete implementation of OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER which inhibited the higher level driver from passing IPv4 packets to/from the driver. Although none of the flag bits in OID_GEN_CURRENT_PACKET_FILTER appears relevant to IPv4 [or IPv6], it mattered. Took a call to Microsoft on my MSDN account to resolve this.